# Got 45 rep for the answer, lost 185 rep when it was deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I think I may have found a bug/oversight when deleting questions and adjusting reputation. I recently answered a question when I was near the reputation cap for the day. As a result I only received 30 rep plus 15 for being the accepted answer.

[image]

However, when the question was deleted a week or so later, I lost 185 rep. 170 for the 17 upvotes, 15 for the accepted answer.

[image]

The problem here is obvious, reputation was removed that was never received. I'm assuming that the reputation cap was not considered when developing this functionality.

Comment: I _think_ that's [status-bydesign]

Comment: Did you get additional reputation for that on other days?

Comment: @sth I did not. All of the rep for that question occurred in one day.

Comment: Did you actually lose 185 rep or is it possible this is just a display bug on the reputation tab?

Comment: I updated the second image to show my rep calc for the day. It *appears* as though the rep is actually lost.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm looking at your account history:

> May 22 moderator recalcs rep   Scheduled: old rep = 18013, new rep = 17968 by Community

In other words, your reputation was adjusted by 45 points only (which matches the reputation you got from the upvotes/acceptance on your answer) and this is just a display bug when a post is removed.

Answer (score 5):

This occurred me several times as well. Just open https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, scroll to the very bottom and press the recalc button.

---

**Update**: I understood that you *actually* lost that much reputation. The recalc should set the reputation score right, not the information in the reputation page --which is in turn indeed a bug. If the recalc didn't change your reputation score, then you *actually* didn't lost that much reputation at all. It's just misinformation in the reputation page.

Comment: I just ran it and nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: The whole reputation skew thing is supposed to be pretty much gone now though, right?  Since the "[Recent reputation history changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)" was rolled out, you're not supposed to have to do recalcs (as they're done automatically in the background within 5 minutes of any reputation event - including deletions).

Comment: @John: The recalc should set the reputation score right, not the information in the reputation page. I understood that you *actually* lost that much rep. If the recalc didn't change your reputation score, then you *actually* didn't lost that much reputation.