# Inconsistent reputations

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

I see some [blank] and inconsistent reputations with the real upvotes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b?tab=reputation) for 2012-08-20

Is this an expected behaviour or some kind of bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about your reputation for dated 20th Aug. have a look at to following image,

[image]

Well as per the reputation rule, you can earn maximum 200 reputation from the upvote/downvote. The upvotes after that limit will not consider any reputation increment. This rule doesnt include accepted reputation or bounty reputation.

Comment: Especially *"This rule doesnt include accepted reputation or bounty reputation."* helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is because the user reached the 200 rep-per-day cap. There can be some inconsistencies when you reach that cap.

Further reading:
[Got 45 rep for the answer, lost 185 rep when it was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134494/got-45-rep-for-the-answer-lost-185-rep-when-it-was-deleted)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32161/181088
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36363/181088

Answer (score 4):

It seems you've hit the reputation cap of 200. Well done. This is explained in [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

The relevant quote is:

> *"You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted
>   separately"*